# Javascript Regex to match 2 URLs

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this kind of URLs that i wanted to match it using RegEx.

1. "http://example.com/sample/company/123/invoices/download/123a_1a23
2. "http://example.com/sample/company/123/invoices/view/123a_12a3"

The first `123` is always numeric, while the 2nd `123a_12a3` is alphanumeric and can have an underscore.

I want to create a regex that will check if it will match those 2 URLs above.

I created this code:

```
let result = new RegExp('\\binvoices/download\\b').test(url);
```

That works but i think there's a better way to do it to match those 2 URLs and maybe check if those 2 parameters exists, because right now that only matches 1.

I'm new to Regex, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: What's in URL and how much of it do you want to test?

Comment: @Phil Those 2 URLs, single test is fine. :)

Comment: I mean do you want to validate the entire URL or only part of it? Do you want to validate the `http` scheme? The hostname? The entire path?

Comment: @Phil ahh, no need to validate the entire URL, only part of it is fine. No need also to validate the `http` scheme or the entire path.

Comment: Please be specific. Right now, your regex just validates that the URL contains `invoices/download` anywhere within it.

Comment: Yup, you're right. That works, but i think there's a better way to do it to match those 2 URLs and maybe check if those 2 parameters exists, because right now that only matches 1 which is "invoices/download". :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should match either of those URLs

```js
const rx = /\/sample\/company\/\d+\/invoices\/(download|view)\/\w+$/

const urls = [
  "http://example.com/sample/company/123/invoices/download/123a_1a23",
  "http://example.com/sample/company/123/invoices/view/123a_12a3",
  "http://example.com/sample/other/123/invoices/view/123a_12a3",
  "http://example.com/sample/company/123/invoices/upload/123a_12a3",
]

urls.forEach(url => console.log(url.slice(18), rx.test(url)))
```

Breaking it down...

```
\/sample\/company\/ - literal "/sample/company/"
\d+                 - one or more numbers
\/invoices\/        - literal "/invoices/"
(download|view)     - "download" or "view"
\/                  - a literal "/"
\w+                 - one or more "word" characters, ie alpha-numeric or underscore
$                   - the end of the string
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I will try it out. I like your second code because i'm not interested in the HTTPS scheme, hostname, or the `sample/company` part of the path.

Comment: BTW, is it possible to add the `sample/company` but not include the `http://example.com` ?

Comment: @PinoyStackOverflower of course. I've updated my answer

Comment: Thank you, my friend. I've accepted this answer. Keep doing what you're doing! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var result = new RegExp('invoices\/(download|view)\/', "i").test(url);
```

the ( and ) parenthesis with a pipe allow you to check two things.